# Bootstrap alert.js Why click the Close button, you can not close the parent parent div?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert, twitter-bootstrap-3

See here: **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YbBXn/)**

Do Bootstrap alert.js parent parent window do not close?
*(From google translate!)*

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
    <h4>Oh snap! You got an error!</h4>
    <p>Change this and that and try again. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
    <ul class="pager">
      <li class="previous"><a href="#" class="text-muted" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></i> Close</a></li>
      <li class="next"><a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></i> View</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because only the parent element to the `data-dismiss` button disappears.  This may very well be a bug that Bootstrap will fix in the future.

One option is just to make sure that your buttons parent element is the alert box.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
  .....
  <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YbBXn/4/

Another work around is making your button trigger a click on another invisible close button that is the direct parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/YbBXn/5/